# How can I change the direction this script is grouping data?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that forms arrays within an overarching array based on duplicate values in `column A`.

`manager 1` its own workbook

`manager 2`

`manager 2` these two would be grouped into another workbook and so on.

problem is, these cells in column A are now transposed as headers in row 1.

How would I edit this script to now group this data by the row headers and take the whole column instead of how the script is originally written?

I figure it has something to do with swapping the `Last = Data(1,i)` or something like that.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim Data, Last, JobFamily
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, a As Long
  Dim Dest As Range

  'Refer to the template
  Set wb = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx")
  'Refer to the destination cell
  Set Dest = wb.Sheets("Sheet11").Range("B1")
  'Read in all data
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Data = .Range("bj2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
  End With
  wb.Activate
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  'Process the data
  For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
    'Manager changes?
    If Data(i, 1) <> Last Then
      'Skip the first
      If i > 1 Then
        'Scroll into the view
        Dest.Select
        'Save a copy
        wb.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
          ValidFileName(Last & ".xlsx")
      End If
      'Clear the employees
      Dest.Resize(, Columns.Count - Dest.Column).EntireColumn.ClearContents
      'Remember this manager
      Last = Data(i, 1)
      'Start the next round
      j = 0
    End If
    'Write the employee data into the template
    a = 0
    For k = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
      Dest.Offset(a, j) = Data(i, k)
      a = a + 1
    Next
    'Next column
    j = j + 1
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called it.  All  references to "Data(i,1)" must be replaced with "Data(1,i)" to transpose the first column of the range into the first row.

Comment: But how would I switch around the range referencing? Before, I was going by values by row, now it's by column. So how would I do something to reference a locked set of rows (52) and a `columns.count).End(xlToLeft))`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. (Xmas.)   I have to admit that I lost the full meaning of your code from the reference to "BJ2" right after the first "with".   So I wasn't sure what in your data was transposed column-for-row besides that first column of data - so I only looked at references to column A or 1.

Comment: In general, of course, you just have to swap column and row in any range reference if the whole sheet is transposed.

The expression to return the cell of the last filled column in Row 1, rather than the last filled row in Column 1, would be:

<code>Cells(1, Cells.columns.count).End(xlToLeft)<code>

But I wasn't sure how that squared with the "BJ2" reference in that line.  Or how BJ2 could be in the upper-left of a range that had the bottom of column 1 as the lower right.  I might need to the see the data to understand what's changed with the transposition.

Comment: As the inevitable dumb question, I don't suppose you could just un-transpose that row back into Column 1?